# Is it possible to add nodes to a graph once its been made?

Tags: c++, graph

Was wondering if it was possible to add and delete nodes from my graph even though it has already been created?

The code below is how I am creating my graph:

```
int V = 6;  // Number of vertices in graph
int E = 18;  // Number of edges in graph 
//graph being created
struct Graph* graph = createGraph(V, E); 
//////////////////////////////////////////////

struct Graph* createGraph(int V, int E) { 
   struct Graph* graph = new Graph; 
   graph->V = V; 
   graph->E = E; 
   graph->edge = new Edge[E]; 
   return graph; 
}
```

Comment: Because of the C-influence on this code, I'm going to say no, not without a lot of work. Turn `Graph::edge` into `std::vector<Edge>` and the difficulty level goes way down, but there can be many, many hidden surprises in the code that's not shown.

Answer (score 1):

It's always possible.  It's just more painful if you use manually allocated arrays:

- to remove a node, you'd need to reduce the value of `graph->E`, and copy every nodes following the one you want to delete to one position earlier, for example with
   [`std::copy(graph->edge+i, graph->edge+graph->E, graph+i-1);`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy)
- to insert a node, you'd need to allocate a new array,  copy all the nodes, add the new one (at the end?), and increment `graph->E`, and `delete[]` the old array.

However, you'd do yourself a favor if you'd use `vector<Edge>` instead.  Then you can dynamically add new nodes with [`graph->edge.pushback()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) and delete nodes with [`graph->edge.erase()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase).  You'd no loner need a graph->E since you could get it on the flow with `graph->edge.size()`.